# wget or curl commands to download ubuntu fonts?

Tags: ssh, fonts, wget, curl, ubuntu-font-family

I `ssh` into my webserver, and I need to grab the ubuntu fonts for my website.

What are the appropriate `wget` or `curl` commands to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like: `wget http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.83.zip` should do it.

Comment: @andrew.46 Well; I need the font family on my server, and I need them unzipped. Provide the commands necessary, and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the Ubuntu Font Family *manually* using `wget` use the following *single command* by copying the entire command and pasting into a Terminal window:

```
wget http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.83.zip && \
sudo mkdir -pv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family && \
sudo unzip -j ubuntu-font-family-0.83.zip 'ubuntu-font-family-0.83/*.ttf' \
-d /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family && \
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Bear in mind that there is an Ubuntu Package for these fonts which can be installed by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

and perhaps this will be enough for you...